# Ansible Error: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

```
kubectl get -n istio-system secret istio-ca -ogo-template='{{index .data "tls.crt"}}' | base64 -d > ca.pem
```

how to run the above command in an ansible playbook?

I am trying to use it as follows:

```
- name: Apply secret istio-ca
  shell: kubectl get -n istio-system secret istio-ca -ogo-template='{{index .data "tls.crt"}}' | base64 -d > ca.pem
  register: sout
```

but this gives me an error as follows:

```
fatal: [172.31.20.135]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'. String: kubectl get -n istio-system secret istio-ca -ogo-template='{{index .data \"tls.crt\"}}' | base64 -d > ca.pem"}
```

Answer (score 5):

I swear this has been answered a thousand times, but I can't immediately find the golang/helm/kubectl specific one in the [thousands of this same error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+end+of+print+statement)

The problem is that jinja2 uses `{{` as its escape syntax, but golang text templating uses `{{` as its escape syntax, and because ansible does not know you mean the golang version, it tried to evaluate your go-template as if it was jinja2 and kaboom

There are two paths out of that situation: [`{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping) or having an outer jinja2 expression that resolves to the inner golang expression

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: kubectl get {% raw %}-ogo-template={{ awesome }}{% endraw %}
- debug:
    msg: kubectl get -ogo-template={{"{{"}} awesome {{"}}"}}
```